# How to use PBR materials as image maps in Sceneform and ARCore?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform, pbr

With reference to the article: [Custom Material Reference](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/custom-material), we can pass the value for `Normal`, `Diffuse`, `Roughness` and `Metalness`.

I want to use custom PBR material as an image map (not a value) in Sceneform and ARCore.

Example maps:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**: Look at **`Mars.sfa`** content in the bottom to find out how to assign `.png` textures to a 3D model.

> Sceneform provides default material definitions (`.sfm` files) to make it easy for developers to get great looking results. Developers who want to deeply customize the way their assets look can create their own material definitions (`.mat` files) and apply them to their assets by specifying the source attribute in the asset definition.

The **material definition format** is a format loosely **based on JSON**. At the top level a material definition is composed of 3 different blocks that use the JSON object notation.

```
material {
    // material properties
}
vertex {
    // vertex shader, THIS BLOCK CAN BE OPTIONAL
}
fragment {
    // fragment shader
}
```

The following code listing shows an example of a valid material definition:

```
material {
    name : "Textured material",
    parameters : [
        {
           type : sampler2d,
           name : texture
        },
        {
           type : float,
           name : metallic
        },
        {
            type : float,
            name : roughness
        }
    ],
    requires : [
        uv0
    ],
    shadingModel : lit,
    blending : opaque
}

fragment {
    void material(inout MaterialInputs material) {

        prepareMaterial(material);
        material.baseColor = texture(materialParams_texture, getUV0());
        material.metallic = materialParams.metallic;
        material.roughness = materialParams.roughness;
    }
}
```

Or fragment part could be like this:

```
fragment {
    void material(inout MaterialInputs material) {

        // fetch the normal in tangent space
        vec3 normal = texture(materialParams_normalMap, getUV0()).xyz;
        material.normal = normal * 2.0 - 1.0;

        // prepare the material
        prepareMaterial(material);

        // from now on, shading_normal, etc. can be accessed
        material.baseColor.rgb = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        material.metallic = 0.0;
        material.roughness = 1.0;
    }
}
```

> Or for instance, look at this sample file that's called **`Mars.sfa`**:

```
{
  materials: [
    {
      name: 'Mars_Atmosphere_Mat',
      parameters: [
        {
          baseColorFactor: [1,1,1,1,],
        },
        {
          baseColor: 'Mars_Atmosphere_Mat_baseColor',
        },
        {
          diffuseColorFactor: null,
        },
        {
          diffuseColor: null,
        },
        {
          normal: null,
        },
        {
          metallicFactor: 1,
        },
        {
          roughnessFactor: 1,
        },
        {
          specularFactor: null,
        },
        {
          glossinessFactor: null,
        },
        {
          specularGlossiness: null,
        },
        {
          specularGlossinessCalculation: null,
        },
        {
          metallicRoughness: null,
        },
        {
          occlusion: null,
        },
        {
          emissiveFactor: [0,0,0,1,],
        },
        {
          emissive: null,
        },
        {
          opacity: null,
        },
      ],
      source: 'build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/gltf_material.sfm',
    },
    {
      name: 'Mars_mat',
      parameters: [
        {
          baseColorFactor: [1,1,1,1,],
        },
        {
          baseColor: 'Mars_mat_baseColor',
        },
        {
          diffuseColorFactor: null,
        },
        {
          diffuseColor: null,
        },
        {
          normal: 'Mars_mat_normal',
        },
        {
          metallicFactor: 0.33000000000000002,
        },
        {
          roughnessFactor: 0.85999999999999999,
        },
        {
          specularFactor: null,
        },
        {
          glossinessFactor: null,
        },
        {
          specularGlossiness: null,
        },
        {
          specularGlossinessCalculation: null,
        },
        {
          metallicRoughness: null,
        },
        {
          occlusion: null,
        },
        {
          emissiveFactor: [0,0,0,1,],
        },
        {
          emissive: null,
        },
        {
          opacity: null,
        },
      ],
      source: 'build/sceneform_sdk/default_materials/gltf_material.sfm',
    },
  ],
  model: {
    attributes: [
      'Position',
      'TexCoord',
      'Orientation',
    ],
    collision: {
      skin_width: 0.75,
    },
    file: 'sampledata/models/Mars/Mars.gltf',
    name: 'Mars',
    recenter: true,
    scale: 0.5,
  },
  samplers: [
    {
      file: 'sampledata/models/Mars/Mars_mat_baseColor.png',
      name: 'Mars_mat_baseColor',
      pipeline_name: 'Mars_mat_baseColor.png',
    },
    {
      file: 'sampledata/models/Mars/Mars_mat_normal.png',
      name: 'Mars_mat_normal',
      params: {
        usage_type: 'Normal',
      },
      pipeline_name: 'Mars_mat_normal.png',
    },
    {
      file: 'sampledata/models/Mars/Mars_Atmosphere_Mat_baseColor.png',
      name: 'Mars_Atmosphere_Mat_baseColor',
      pipeline_name: 'Mars_Atmosphere_Mat_baseColor.png',
    },
  ],
  version: '0.54:1',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [OBJ Attributes](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/sfa#obj_material)

If you are using an `obj` file, you need to make a custom material. [Here is an example custom material](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/c581b755fd8d36aa3c9e44e6964e836b15743330/android/samples/textured-object/app/src/main/materials/textured_pbr.mathttps://github.com/google/filament/blob/master/samples/materials/aiDefaultMat.mat) that has everything you need.

### [FBX Attributes](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/sfa#fbx_material)

If you are using an `fbx` file, these are provided by default:

- `baseColorMap`
- `metallicMap`
- `normalMap`
- `roughnessMap`

### [GLTF Attributes](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/sfa#gltf_material)

If you are using a `gltf` file, then you need to combine the metallic and roughness maps into one. Occlusion can also be packed into the same texture map. Red is occlusion, green roughness, and blue metallic. The parameter in the `sfa` file for this is:

`metallicRoughness`